# Cannot get results from stored procedure

Tags: npgsql

I have a stored procedure named `get_all_buildings()` with a body defined as such:

```
SELECT * FROM building;
```

I am invoking the procedure like so:

```
using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
await connection.OpenAsync();
var sql = "CALL get_all_buildings();";
using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, connection);
using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
while(reader.Read())
{
    doSomething();
}
```

I will never reach the call to `doSomething()`. If I replace the query text with the definition of the stored procedure, I am able to hit the line that calls `doSomething()`. If I execute the SQL above in PGAdmin, I see the results come back (albeit the default view is the messages tab). The only scenario where no results are returned is when I call the procedure this way. I have not had an issue calling other procedures which execute with an `IN/OUT` variable and a corresponding call to `ExecuteScalarAsync()`. I have tried using the synchronous call `ExecuteReader()` still with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL stored procedures don't return data - you're probably looking to create a function instead. [This article](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/everything-you-need-know-about-postgres-stored-procedures-and-functions) summarizes the differences between procedures and functions quite well.